# Web App UX row selection best practice

Tags: user-interface, web, user-experience

Which is a better User Experience / Design decision for opening a table row (in a business website)? To place an "Open" button like this:

[image]

Or, to allow the row to be opened by clicking anywhere on it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question assumes that people understand that there is more information to be gained by "expanding" these rows in this table. As this is designed right now, there are zero hints for a user that they are capable of viewing more information inside the same view that they are using.

Option 1: Open button

Let's assume (dangerously) that people are knowledgable that they can use this table to view more info about a line item in this table. The button itself is separated from the content it is referring to, breaking Fitt's Law. Also, the label is "open", which most users would interpret as taking them to another page, or opening a new context. "View More" or "Expand" would be a better label.

Option 2: Click anywhere

This is slightly better than the button, as it clearly relates the action to the content. However, it still doesn't solve the problem of exposing the functionality to the user.

I would recommend a combination of both of these approaches, making sure you are solving for Fitt's Law as well as exposing a label that will tell the users what functionality is present in these table rows, and how to access them.